# How to resolve Do not nest generic types in member signatures?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sonarqube

I am getting error like Do not nest generic types in member signatures ?
Please tell me how to resolve this error easily ?

```
public Orderable<T> Asc<TKey>(Expression<Func<T, TKey>> keySelector)
        {
            _queryable = _queryable
                .OrderBy(keySelector);
            return this;
        }
public Orderable<T> Asc<TKey1, TKey2>(Expression<Func<T, TKey1>> keySelector1,
                                              Expression<Func<T, TKey2>> keySelector2)
        {
            _queryable = _queryable
                .OrderBy(keySelector1)
                .OrderBy(keySelector2);
            return this;
        }
```

Thanks,

Comment: This "error message" is meant for things like `Dictionary<T1, Dictionary<T2, List<T3>>>`. There's no point in simplifying the `Expression<Func<T, TKey>>` and I would simply ignore it.

Comment: in sonar it's showing as error Expression<Func<T, TKey>>.

Comment: Consider a design where 'Orderable<T>.Asc<TKey>(Expression<Func<T, TKey>>)' doesn't nest generic type 'Expression<Func<T, TKey>>'.

Comment: There should be a way to suppress the warnings in SonarQube. Maybe using a [SuppressMessageAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.suppressmessageattribute.aspx) works. I don't see a way to change the code to avoid the message.

Comment: public InArgument<List<string>> Name{ get; set; }
  public InArgument<List<string>> Address { get; set; }can you tell how to resolve the above code also showing same error donot nest generic types in member signature ?

Comment: You can make a specialized `class StringList: List<string>` and then use `InArgument<StringList>`.

Comment: my page not having List type strings ,having so many types collection,dicttionary like that  public InArgument<Collection<Attachment>> Attachments { get; set; }
  public InArgument<List<string>> Name{ get; set; }
  public InArgument<List<string>> Address{ get; set; }
  public InArgument<IDictionary<string, string>> tickets { get; set; }

Comment: How to resolve the error "donot nest generic types " in above lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must declare every generic typ you use in the method declaration, like this:

```
public Orderable<T> Asc<T, TKey>(Expression<Func<T, TKey>> keySelector)
            {
                _queryable = _queryable
                    .OrderBy(keySelector);
                return this;
            }
```

Comment: That's not really an answer to the question, and you don't have to specify <T, TKey> if it's already defined at the class level.

Comment: @Drik getting error as -Consider a design where 'Orderable<T>.Asc<TKey>(Expression<Func<T, TKey>>)' doesn't nest generic type 'Expression<Func<T, TKey>>'.